# How to sort items in a query inside a variant?

Tags: sxa, sitecore-query

I need to sort items returning from a query inside a variant. For example query:.//*[@@templatename='Template']. I need to sort these items since it doesn't work through build query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

While using Variant Query you can use:

- normal Sitecore query
- Sitecore content search query

Try something like this:

```
+template:{7826b36e-d813-40cf-aa33-26132ff2dad6};sort:published
+template:{7826b36e-d813-40cf-aa33-26132ff2dad6};sort:published[desc]
```

where `published` is field of an item. Use your field there.

Comment: when i add "query:./*;sort:published" there are no results returned at all, do you have another idea?

Comment: Try to use Content Search query.